# Python is reading my data with NANS and Infs, but they don't have any

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data, data-cleaning, feature-scaling

I'm having an issue in Python where it says that the dataframe I have loaded through `pandas.read_csv()` cannot be scaled using `StandardScaler()`because of the presence of Inf values or values too big for `dtype(float)` I checked in R (I am more comfortable with this language, but have to use Python for this project) and it shows that the dataframe does not have any Inf values or NAs.

Are there restrictions in Python that converts large numbers or small numbers to NA/NaN/Inf?

Thanks.

Comment: There is, could you provide code so we can reproduce your errors and investigate where it comes from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pandas.DataFrame.describe()` to find the values that are present in the feature and see which specific values might be an issue.